# What's best practice in terms of handling Gift Aid within CiviCRM

Tags: gift-aid-extension

I'm just setting up the 3.0 beta Gift aid extension (https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.giftaid and https://civicrm.org/extensions/gift-aid-extension-uk), as provided by Compucorp (and for which many thanks) for CiviCRM 4.6.

However I'm a tad confused, because there's also the Gift Aid Online Submission extension from Veda Consulting (https://civicrm.org/extensions/uk-hmrc-online-gift-aid-submission). Studying the available documentation, neither extension appears to reference or make mention in any way of the other. I've a vague memory from CiviCon London a few years back that the online submission extension builds on the Compucorp extension by enabling straightforward submission direct to HMRC, but I'm not clear. Can anyone cast any light?

If I can get some clarity, through my own experience and that of other folks that have gone through this I'll be happy to write it up in a way that might be helpful to other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - the Veda extension is for submitting the Gift Aid application to HMRC and the Compucorp one does the rest. It's a shame this isn't better documented. Be careful of the version of the Compucorp one though, as I don't believe the one of the Civi extensions page works with 4.6 - get a working version from Git [here](https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.giftaid)